Add pivoting toggles to acrylic panel
I'm wanting to make a removeable acrylic panel that sits in my casement window frame. It's going to have my air con hose through it, just FYI.
I have been looking at different methods to secure it in the frame temporarily and I thought about pivoting toggles that will pull against the inside of the window to stop it falling out.
My initial idea was to have an M6 bolt through from the outside to the inside, a 25mm nylon spacer (to match the window frame thickness) and then a toggle of some sort, possibly also made out of acrylic.

My question here is more around the construction and the correct hardware to use... Is my construction correct here?
I am sure I will need washers of some sort in order to enable the pivoting, between the spacer and toggle and again between toggle and nut; and I'm sure I'll need a washer between the the head of the bolt and the acrylic panel.
Will acrylic be up to the job? Should I instead go polycarbonate?
Will the configuration of washers and spacers be sufficient to allow the pivoting of the toggle?

@RMDman Am I sane?

That is off topic here. Try the psychiatry stack.

You have two acrylic panels?

@Huesmann apologies, I should have labelled it better. I have now updated my Q and the diagram

Your "toggles" are actually "dogs"
Acrylic has a tendency to crack when drilled. I would instead put the dogs on the window frame. I would use factory made flyscreen dogs.
"dog" is not a useful term to search on the internet, try "flyscreen swivel clip"

I find that half of the battle of DIYing things is not knowing the correct names or terms to search. Swivel clips it is!
